# Necessary conditions for a Reedy fibrant diagram

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $C$ be a model category and $\Delta$ be the simplex category. Denote by $Func(\Delta, C)$ the diagram category which has a Reedy model structure. Now let $X$ be a Reedy fibrant diagram  in $Func(\Delta, C)$.

Then what are the necessary conditions for $X$ to be fibrant.  I think one can show $X$ is pointwise fibrant. Is it also true that the maps $X_{n} \rightarrow X_{m}$ are fibrations in $C$.

Comment: Reedy fibrant diagrams are automatically projectively fibrant.  They are also injectively fibrant if C is a Cisinski model category.

Comment: The category $C$ which I have in my mind is a Cisinski model category (Bisimplicial sets with injective/reedy model structure). Is the second statement true? (about the maps in diagram being fibrations)

Comment: No, the second claim is false.  Injective fibrancy coincides with Reedy fibrancy, which in its turn boils down to saying that the matching maps are fibrations.  The matching maps only use the value of X on surjective maps [m]→[n].  So you cannot expect that X sends an injective map to a fibration.  For instance, it is easy to construct a counterexample where X_0→X_n is not a fibration.  But the same argument implies that X_m→X_n is a fibration if [m]→[n] is surjective.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov can you give me a reference for your first comment as i need to use this ; If i understand your comment then for a cosimplicial-simplicial set or cosimplicial-bisimplicial set, being Reedy fibrant is same as injective fibrant , right?

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between what I answered (Reedy and injective coincide for simplicial objects) and what you asked (about cosimplicial objects).  The coincidence is shown here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elegant+Reedy+category#reedy__injective, but it requires Δ^op to be an elegant Reedy category, which it isn't, only the category Δ is.  For *co*simplicial objects the injective and Reedy model structures are different.  However, the other claims stand: cosimplicial Reedy fibrancy can be characterized explicitly by saying that the matching map X_n→lim_{m<n} X_m is a fibration.

Comment: Reedy fibrancy of cosimplicial objects requires that certain maps are fibrations. 
 The first few maps are X_0→1, X_1→X_0×X_0, X_2→X_1×_{X_0}X_1, X_3→eq(X_2×X_2×X_2,X_1×X_1×X_1).  From this explicit description you can deduce, for example, that X_f:X_m→X_n is a fibration for a surjective map f:m→n, but it is not true that X_f is a fibration if f is not surjective.

Comment: ok, i understand.Thanks. Do you know of any criteria of calculating homotopy limit of a cosimplicial diagram of simplicial sets (apart from taking the usual limit of injective fibrant diagram) . Will taking Reedy fibrant diagram suffice? (i know that $\Delta$ is with fibrant constants not cofibrant constants)

Comment: If the diagram is Reedy fibrant (which is a weaker condition than injective fibrancy), one can take the weighted limit with respect to the standard weight Δ→sSet that sends [m] to Δ^m.  In other words, the homotopy limit can be computed as the equalizer ∏_m X_m ⇉ ∏_{f:m→n} X_n.  This is reminiscent of the formula that calculates the homotopy limit of a projectively fibrant diagram using the weight [m]↦N(Δ/m), but it is much easier to work with Δ^m than with N(Δ/m), which is pretty big.